# How to make an async rust lib safe when lib user may fail (Ref)Cell borrow checks depending on the calls and callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I need to get an idea how to solve this problem the Rust way, because my program is panicking.

My lib has a loop for checking events and run closures. At current I'm fighting with the simple close event. My engine has an API for registering the on close event and closing a window.

```rust
// lib user code
// registering a callback which closes the window, when s.o. click the 'X'
let window_id = window.window_id;
engine.window_on_close(window.window_id, Box::new(|env| {
    env.engine.window_close(window_id);
}));

// lib code
// polling events (the glfw way)
for window in self.windows.borrow_mut().values_mut() {
    for (_, event) in glfw::flush_messages(&window.events) {
        match event {
            glfw::WindowEvent::Close => {
                window.invoke_on_close(&ce)?;
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}

// struct Engine
pub fn window_on_close(&mut self, func: F)
    // where F: ...
{
    // ...
}

pub fn window_close(&mut self, window_id: glfw::WindowId) {
    let mut windows = self.windows.borrow_mut(); // panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'
    let mut window = windows.remove(&window_id).expect("fix me");
    window.close();
}
```

When I click the 'X' it's panicking.

Another thing is, that this is a lib, so I have no idea whether the lib user closes the window on close event (which is panicking) or if the user only prints "hello, close" which would work and I think that's a bad design issue for a lib, if a lib user runs into panics because any RefCell borrow checks are failing.

To make it more clear, I write the code down in a linear fashion. Of course now you and I can see what's the problem of `borrow_mut()` twice which could be avoided when writing this code directly, but my lib is only running code from userland for the close event and as the lib user wants to close the window, this fails. Anyway now one can see, that the code has a bug, as it's mutating a hash map without an iterator while iterating over it:

```rust
// 1. lib user registers close event:
let window_id = window.window_id;
engine.window_on_close(window.window_id, Box::new(|env| {
    env.engine.window_close(window_id);
}));

// 2. lib code polling events (the glfw way)
for window in self.windows.borrow_mut().values_mut() { // HERE: borrow_mut()
    for (_, event) in glfw::flush_messages(&window.events) {
        match event {
            glfw::WindowEvent::Close => {
                // pasted code from the callback: `engine.window_close(...)`
                let mut windows = self.window.borrow_mut(); // HERE: borrow_mut()
                let mut window = windows.remove(&window_id).expect("fix me");
                window.close();
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Am I correct, that actually the only thing I have to fix is that lib user should not be able to run any window mutations, because windows is already borrowed. Anything else would be fine.

What would be your suggestion for this?

Comment: What does this have to do with async?

Comment: If I'm reading between the lines correctly, this is just "how to remove elements while iterating" with extra stuff in the way? The first option is somewhat common, the second option sounds dubious since you're already using interior mutability and it hasn't helped.

Comment: @vallentin it's not `rust-async` but it's async code, so when I call back I have no idea what the user does and it may end in borrowing twice

Comment: @kmdreko removing while iterating would be easy, but it's `calling back while iterating` and lib user (callback implementor) may run an API fn mutating the data structure I'm iterating on so it's panicking.